# aws-sdk-php v3.44 fails to sendMessage to SQS FIFO Queue: MessageGroupId missing?

Tags: php, queue, amazon-sqs, fifo, aws-php-sdk

I am using the Amazon SDK for PHP version 3.44 (released 2017-11-30). I can connect to my Amazon SQS account and execute the listQueues(), getQueueUrl(), getQueueAttributes(), and receiveMessage() commands just fine. However, the sendMessage() command consistently fails with the following message:

> The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.

I am most definitely including this parameter. It doesn't seem to matter which version of the aws-sdk-php API I use, this message keeps coming back. Here is my code:

```
$queue = SqsClient::factory([
    'profile'     => $profile,
    'region'      => $region,
    'version'     => '2012-11-05',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
]);
$queue_list = $queue->listQueues(); // ok
$url        = $queue->getQueueUrl(['QueueName'=>$queue_name]); // ok
$received   = $queue->receiveMessage(['QueueUrl'=>$url->get('QueueUrl')]); // ok
$response   = $queue->sendMessage([
    'MessageBody'    => $message,
    'MessageGroupId' => $message_group_id,
    'QueueUrl'       => $url->get('QueueUrl'),
]); // fails with message indicating MessageGroupId is missing
```

I have spent several hours searching for a working example of sending a message up to an Amazon SQS FIFO queue through the PHP SDK, and am beginning to believe this is not possible. Has anybody out there been able to get the aws-sdk-php library to work with an SQS FIFO queue?

Comment: `$message_group_id` is definitely populated? My thinking is maybe a null is interpreted as no parameter?

Comment: Yes, I changed out the value for MessageGroupId with literals and scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is creating an instance of SqsClient, not creating a SQS queue.  You still still need to call $queue->createQueue.  See the documentation.  For fifo queues, you will need to enable "FifoQueue" to "true", and set up the "ContentBasedDeduplication" when creating the queue.  When you send your message, depending on the ContentBasedDeduplication setting of the queue you created, you may or may not also need to send a "MessageDeduplicationId" along with the "MessageGroupId".

From your code, I can't see how you created the Queue.

- Did you enable fifo queues with the property "FifoQueue" => "true"
- Did you set "ContentBasedDeduplication" to "true" or "false" ?
- Did you name your queue with the extension ".fifo" ?

I did all of these things, and configured my queue with ContentBasedDeduplication set to "false".  When I send a message, the only other property that I'm sending that you aren't (along with the MessageGroupId) is MessageDeduplicationId.  I'm able to send messages to the fifo queue just fine using sdk 3.44.

Comment: You have described how to programmatically set up an SQS FIFO queue. Are you also able to send a message to that queue using the aws-sdk-php v3 framework? This is what the question is about in particular.

Comment: I have manually created my queue through the Amazon SQS web interface. I set up the queue to use FIFO and checked the box to force Content Based Deduplication. Though I did not create the queue programmatically, I should still be able to use the above code to insert messages into the queue. However, I consistently receive the error message, "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId." Do you see anything wrong with the posted code? Could you post your working code as an example so I may compare your sendMessage() function to mine?

Comment: is it named with the .fifo extension?  I'm not sure if that your issue or not, but if i try to work with a fifo queue that doesn't have this extension, I get the error msg: The name of a FIFO queue can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or underscores, must end with .fifo suffix and be 1 to 80 in length.   The extension requirement is in the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the help, Michael. I ran my code again and it started working. I did not change any queue settings. I did not change any PHP code. I got the silly error message before, and I don't receive it now. I suspect Amazon quietly fixed something on their end. As you noted, the code just works as we would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Amazon has quietly resolved whatever bug was blocking my API call. I did not change my queue settings or my code. The same API call that resulted in error messages last week now runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on 3.3.0 forever.  In my case, I just needed to upgrade to 3.44.2, then pass in MessageDeduplicationId in addition to MessageGroupId.  I would probably double check your SDK version if you run into this issue.